Placing two different bibliographies using ONLY "natbib" package
I am looking for a way to place two different bibliographies in a Latex document. One after the conclusion and the other in the Appendix (using two different .bib files).
The journal prohibits using "multibib" and "biblatex" packages and allows only the "natbib" package.
Any suggestions?

create two dummy documents that cite the entries you want in the bibliography, compile them and create the bbl, then load these in your main document.

welcome! are you sure you are allowed two bibliographies in this case?

I would strongly advise you to check with the journal's style guide, as my strong suspicion is that you are wasting your time (i.e., they will lump all of the references into one list anyway). Journals often re-typeset your citations anyway, as they need to make hyperlinks, make sure the articles actually exist, and so forth.

You can manually create the bibliographies with \begin{thebibliography}{}. This is cumbersome, but gets the job done. If you can, you should add the bibentry package. This allows you to do \nobibliography{<file>}\bibliographystyle{plainnat} which processes the .bib file, allowing you to for example use \citet{}. It also works without the bibentry package, but then you get "(authour?) [2]" when doing \citet{}:

Versus with the bibentry fix:

MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

% Pseudo .bib file
\begin{filecontents}{combined.bib}
@article{key1,
  author = {Author A},
  title = {Title of the Main Document Reference},
  journal = {Journal Name},
  year = {2024},
  volume = {12},
  pages = {34--56}
}
@article{key2,
  author = {Author B},
  title = {Another Main Document Reference},
  journal = {Journal Name},
  year = {2023},
  volume = {10},
  pages = {78--90}
}
@article{akey1,
  author = {Appendix Author A},
  title = {Title of the Appendix Reference},
  journal = {Another Journal},
  year = {2022},
  volume = {5},
  pages = {12--34}
}
@article{akey2,
  author = {Appendix Author B},
  title = {Another Appendix Reference},
  journal = {Another Journal},
  year = {2021},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {45--67}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

% Main document content
\section{Introduction}
This is the main content of the document. \citet{key1} is an example citation.

\section{Conclusion}
Concluding remarks go here. Another citation: \citet{key2}.

% Main bibliography (manually constructed)
\renewcommand{\refname}{References}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{key1} Author A. Title of the Main Document Reference. \textit{Journal Name}, 2024, vol. 12, pp. 34--56.
\bibitem{key2} Author B. Another Main Document Reference. \textit{Journal Name}, 2023, vol. 10, pp. 78--90.
\end{thebibliography}

\clearpage
\appendix

\section{Additional Information}
This is the appendix content. For example, \citet{akey1}.

% Appendix bibliography (manually constructed)
\renewcommand{\refname}{Appendix References}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{akey1} Appendix Author A. Title of the Appendix Reference. \textit{Another Journal}, 2022, vol. 5, pp. 12--34.
\bibitem{akey2} Appendix Author B. Another Appendix Reference. \textit{Another Journal}, 2021, vol. 7, pp. 45--67.
\end{thebibliography}

\nobibliography{combined} % Process the bib file but don't print the bibliography

\end{document}



